# DynamoDB local cors example

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use the 'cors' parameter of the DynamoDB local (latest version) but it's not working except for the '*'. The documentation says "You must provide a comma-separated 'allow' list of specific domains." I've tried using "example.com", ".example.com" and "www.example.com" but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any suggestions how to get this to work?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: *"Nothing seems to work"* is pretty broad. Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: I left a reply on the aws forum post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=186319

Comment: After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/661414 and switching to a Crome-based browser it worked for me.